# websphere server's X.509 certificate cannot be trusted

Tags: java, security, ssl-certificate, websphere, websphere-8

We are running on WAS 8.5.5.16, we replaced a self signed certificate with a signed one. After this change we are seeing this vulnerability in vulnerability management tool which is tenable for us.
It shows that the certificate can't be trusted and has expired when we check in WAS console all certs are valid and we are unable to find which cert is causing the issue.

Any pointers/suggestions to help understand how to find/fix this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You have to check what kind of ports that vulnerability management tool checks, and see what certs it complains about.... Maybe it shows at least some detailed data about the expiring cert that could help you identify it.

Comment: So if you were changing the self signed certs to CA certs because they were going to expire, check to see if the certs that are expiring are the same as the ones you thought you replaced.  There are certificates/signers in the key.p12 / trust.p12 in the (profilename)/etc directory

Comment: thanks for the update, is there a way in WAS to find out which cert may be causing the issue ? any traces string that may help ? any way to find it out using any files in the installation directory or by any other way ? thanks